# why ontouchstart event triggers the handler twice in react?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, ontouchstart

I observed this weird behaviour that when using ontouchstart, the event handler is triggered twice but when I switched to onclick, it was triggered once. Why is it like this?

Comment: Can you provide some code? It's quite difficult to understand what's wrong without an example.

Comment: Can you share your code please?